# Having trouble running more than one vmware VM simultaneously on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, vmware

I have a i7 machine with 8GB RAM and two external harddisks, both contains a NTFS partition, today I noticed some gaps while booting a second vm under Ubuntu, which took more than 5 minutes to boot up, I usually do the same under Windows and both vms boots up reasonabily well.

What's the best filesystem to format my HDD in order to get the best virtualization experience under Ubuntu? Ext4? And what if I need to share VMs between Windows and Linux? Will FAT32 or exFAT give better performance while running VMs on Ubuntu and Windows as well?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research about this topic I really noticed several people complaining about NTFS performance on Linux, especially for virtualization purposes.

The best filesystem to be used on my external hard disks is ext4, followed by ext3 and xfs.

More details can be found [here](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/linux-a-unix/34-btrfs-ext3-ext4-xfs-and-kvm-virtual-machine-a-host-side-filesystem-comparison.html).

**UPDATE**

I looks like the following line on vmx file could help me on get more than one vm running at same time in a external HDD using NTFS:

```
mainmem.backing = "swap"
```